# What is the purpose of /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3?

Tags: debian, xorg

Today I've spotted a process that tends to go AWOL:

```
username 1505  2.4  1.7 391380 70216 tty2     Sl+  20:36   3:19 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3
```

Can anyone explain what is its purpose?

System details:

```
4.17.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.17.8-1 (2018-07-20) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 8):

It's your X-Server.

It's the core process that handles all your graphical output.

If you run Firefox, it talks to the X-Server and tells it "draw line". The X-Server then actually talks to your graphics hardware.

For further details, maybe wikipedia's [X window System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) might be helpful?

Comment: can you explain better that process? I have the same thing but I have Debian under VirtualBox and Debian run very slow.